# How we can add the botlibre bot to bb messenger app

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I'm trying to create a bbm chat bot using **nodejs** sdk.
I'm following this [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/files/bbm-enterprise/documents/guide/html/examples/javascript/Node/README.html).
Using this I created a chatbot in botlibre.
Here my problem is, how we can add that bot to my **BB messenger android app** to send messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to connect a bot with the BBM Consumer app, as they do not exist under the same SDK ‘domain’.

The BBM Consumer and BBM Enterprise apps that are downloaded from iTunes or the PlayStore are not connected to the ones that you are building with the BBM Enterprise SDK. Your bot will not be able to chat with these applications, but it can chat with your own mobile applications that are built with the BBM Enterprise SDK (BlackBerry Communications Platform).

Answer (score 3):

After you have created your bot in botlibre, click on 'embed', and then copy the SDK.applicationId and web.instance fields. Put these values into the config.js file of the Node SDK under the botlibre field. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEAB5.png)

Make sure you have requested a domain for use with the BBM Enterprise SDK. You can get one [here](http://account.good.com).

Comment: Both I did. I created a bot in botlibre and got a domain from BBM. I gave all these things in my config.js. How I can invite this bot to my **BB messenger mobile ap**p for sending messages to chat bot